# cordova - Error: Failed to fetch platform android on azure buiild pipeline

Tags: android, azure, cordova, project, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on `azure build pipeline` and trying to run the task of ionic command to `cordova add platform android` and while running the command I am getting an error mentioned below.

```
    Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@7.1.4
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
    Failed to get absolute path to installed module
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    cordova platform add android --save exited with exit code 1.
```

I am using a hosted mac agent `macOS-10.14`to on azure DevOps to run a build pipeline.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?